How to get yaml_parse_file() to preserve blank lines?
In PHP 8.3, I'm reading a file with yaml_parse_file() that looks like this:
summary: "Apples

Apples are a delicious fruit, unless they have worms in them."

When I json_encode() the array generated with parse_yaml_file() and then output that to a file, the output looks like this:
Apples
Apples are a delicious fruit, unless they have worms in them."

So it seems yaml_parse_file() is trimming whitespace, and it's removing the blank line between Apples and Apples are a delicious fruit.
However, I need to keep that blank line.  Is there an easy way to keep it, or do I have to add it back in after yaml_parse_file() removes it?

@ChrisHaas Whoops, I meant yaml_parse_file().  Thanks, updated!

This is not a bug in the PHP parser, this is defined as part of the YAML spec:

In a multi-line double-quoted scalar, line breaks are subject to flow line folding, which discards any trailing white space characters. It is also possible to escape the line break character. In this case, the escaped line break is excluded from the content and any trailing white space characters that precede the escaped line break are preserved. Combined with the ability to escape white space characters, this allows double-quoted lines to be broken at arbitrary positions.


it's removing the blank line between Apples and Apples are a delicious fruit.

Note that it's the completely blank line which is being preserved, and the newline at the end of the first line is what's being cut.
To avoid this, you could encode your YAML with escape sequences instead:
summary: "Apples\n\nApples are a delicious fruit, unless they have worms in them."

Or perhaps just include one extra explicit blank to make up for the one being stripped:
summary: "Apples


Apples are a delicious fruit, unless they have worms in them."

You could also use the special pipe | character to indicate a block literal (but then you have to consider indentation):
summary: |
  Apples

  Apples are a delicious fruit, unless they have worms in them.

